# spring boot zuul causing cors failed at web browser

Tags: spring-boot, netflix-zuul

I have configured cors for zuul to check the origin etc.

Below is the code I added in zuul service, my zull proxy forward this request to back service and I want this cors to be tested on zuul before sending to back end micro service

```
@Component
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class SimpleCORSFilter implements Filter {

    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SimpleCORSFilter.class);

    @Value("${myserver.origin}")
    private String origin;


    public SimpleCORSFilter() {
        logger.info("SimpleCORSFilter init");
    }

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {


            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", origin);
            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, PUT, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Authorization, Content-Type, x-requested-with, Accept,username,idType");
            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
/*
            if ("OPTIONS".equalsIgnoreCase(((HttpServletRequest) req).getMethod())) {
                response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
            } else {
                chain.doFilter(req, res);
            }   
*/

 chain.doFilter(req, res);
    }
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {
    }

    public void destroy() {}
}
```

I have configured myserver.origin=**http://172.160.128.10:9898**

In Chrome browser I am getting as failed(403) error

From Chrome I captured the log.

General:

```
Request URL: http://172.160.128.10:9898/api/test
Request Method: OPTIONS
Status Code: 403 
Remote Address: 172.160.128.10:9898
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

Response Headers

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization,Content-Type,Accept,username
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, PUT, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://172.160.128.60:8080
Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600
Allow: GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, PATCH
Date: Fri, 04 Oct 2019 12:12:32 GMT
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

Request Headers

```
Access-Control-Request-Headers: content-type
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Origin: http://172.160.128.10:8080
Referer: http://172.160.128.10:8080/api/
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.90 Safari/537.36
```

**So from browser it is getting failed though it is sending correct fields**

Comment: No CORS configuration you do is going to cause the server to block requests from curl. And no CORS configuration you do is going to change the HTTP status code of any responses. The only effect that CORS configuration will have is to cause the server to send back additional response headers. That’s it.

Comment: Okay.. I have a frontend UI which calls my APIs.. if remove the If OPTIONS check he is always getting 403 though everything is proper -- adding only chain.doFilter(req, res);